# Tree works in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, tree

I am working on a project and having some diffuculties becauuse Im not used to Haskell and it's a somehow hard language for me to code.

I want a tree that has leaf and branches, leaves will be only inputs as an integer like 1,2,3.
Branches will be chars only for operation1 and operation2.

these ops get inputs from leaves and do calculation and send the output to other branch and do calculation again until it goes to top one.

Code I have so far:

```
data Tree = Leaf Float | Branch Char Tree Tree deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

insertElement x (Leaf y) = Leaf y

insertElement x (Branch a left right) = Branch a (insertElement x left) right                                                           
doIt (x:xs) (y:ys) =  insertElement ((Branch y (Leaf x) (Leaf (head xs))))                                  

op1 num1 num2 = 1+num1+num2*2
op2 num1 num2 = 1-num1*num2*2
```

Tree will be created recursively, I tried to use foldr for to do that but didnt work because its not a binary tree.

Any helps would be good.

Comment: I cannot write multiple statements also for recursion :) Its a haskell thing I guess...

Comment: It would be really nice if you used Hlint and made type annotations to your functions; this helps both the compiler AND us to reason about your code

Comment: it also helps a lot if your functions have reasonable names - like insertChar/insertElement, but doIt is saying nothing at all

Comment: Your problem statement is quite hard to understand. I think you want to represent syntactic trees for a simple expression language made of numeric constants and two operations (op1,op2). Your `doIt` function is meant to evaluate the represented expression. I still do not see the purpose of the `insertElement`, though.

Comment: @AtikBayraktar I rolled back your edit so that your code can be seen.  This will help others who come across this question searching for the solution to a similar problem.  It is considered polite to leave your full question up, but feel free to add additional edits below the text of your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem, but maybe you want something like this:

```
data Op = Op1 | Op2
data Tree = Leaf Float | Branch Op Tree Tree

eval :: Tree -> Float
eval (Leaf x) = x
eval (Branch Op1 l r) = op1 (eval l) (eval r)
eval (Branch Op2 l r) = op2 (eval l) (eval r)

op1 :: Float -> Float -> Float
op1 num1 num2 = 1+num1+num2*2
op2 :: Float -> Float -> Float
op2 num1 num2 = 1-num1*num2*2

example :: Float
example = eval (Branch Op1 (Leaf 3) (Branch Op2 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 1)))
```

If that is what you want to do, consider using a less general type than `Tree`, such as

```
data Exp = Lit Float | Op1 Exp Exp | Op2 Exp Exp
eval :: Exp -> Float
eval (Lit x) = x
eval (Op1 l r) = op1 (eval l) (eval r)
...
```

Comment: Yes, actually I thought it before to make ops as a data but didnt know that I could use it in my tree. Thanks for that. I will try it.

Comment: I am trying to make it recursively operate for a list of values. Foldr could work with one list but I have 2 list for inputs leaf and ops whether it is 1 or 2. What do you suggest? It will read it from tree now I see, so I have to create tree recursively and then do operations.. God haskell is annoying.. that was my problem that I asked btw :)

Comment: fixed it by that way... Thanks :)